# Error: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, email

I have VB.NET code below that reads from a SQL Server database.

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GasNominationsConnectionString").ConnectionString)

    conn.Open()
    Using cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "getEmailAddress"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("company", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "RWET"
        Dim sqlrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If sqlrd.HasRows Then
            While sqlrd.Read()
                msg.[To].Add(New MailAddress("emailAddress"))
            End While
        End If
    End Using

End Using
```

The data in the SQL Server table is a list of 2 email addresses but I get an error

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are creating a new MailAddress object with value "emailAddress" with this line :

```
msg.[To].Add(New MailAddress("emailAddress"))
```

"emailAddress" is indeed not a valid email address.

You should take your values in your sqlrd["emailAddress"] with something like this (don't remember the exact format in VB.net):

```
msg.[To].Add(New MailAddress(sqlrd["emailAddress"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `"emailAddress"` is not an email-address. You need to read from the reader:

```
Using sqlrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If sqlrd.HasRows Then
        While sqlrd.Read()
             Dim email = sqlrd.GetString(sqlrd.GetOrdinal("emailAddress"))
             msg.[To].Add(New MailAddress(email))
        End While
    End If
End Using
```